# Inserir os valores de um vetor de tamanho N na mesma linha Python

Tags: python

Bem, fiz o código a seguir, que se baseia em dois vetores de tamanho N que, multiplicando os valores de mesmo indice forma um terceiro vetor resultante dessa multiplicação.

```
n = int(input(''))
vetor1 = []
vetor2 = []
resultante = []
for vet in range(n):
    if n >=1 and n <= 100:
        vetor1.append(int(input()))
for vet in range(n):
    if n >=1 and n <= 100:
        vetor2.append(int(input()))
resultante = [elemvetor1 * elemvetor2  for elemvetor1, elemvetor2 in zip(vetor1, vetor2)]
resultantef =' '.join(str(v) for v in resultante)
print(resultantef)
```

O problema surge da minha entrada, já que os N valores do vetor1 precisam estar em uma linha e os N valores do vetor2 precisam estar em uma segunda linha. Segue um exemplo de entrada para a respectiva saída:

```
#entrada
5 #tamanho dos vetores 1 e 2
1 3 2 4 5 #valores do vetor1
6 8 9 7 6 #valores do vetor 2

#saída
6 24 18 28 30 #vetor3 resultante das multiplicações de mesmo indice entre vetor1 e vetor2
```

Comment: Isso responde sua pergunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253863/how-to-input-2-integers-in-one-line-in-python

Comment: @VitorCeolin Testei aqui conforme o dito na pergunta q vc linkou, não deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja implementar um código que seja capaz de montar dois vetores de mesmo tamanho e um terceiro vetor, no qual, cada um de seus elementos sejam o produto dos elementos de mesmo índices dos dois vetores anteriores.

Para isso você pode utiliza o seguinte código:

```
n = int(input())
vetor1 = list()
vetor2 = list()
resultante = list()
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    v1 = int(input(f'Digite {c}º elemento do 1º vetor: '))
    v2 = int(input(f'Digite {c}º elemento do 2º vetor: '))
    v = (v1 * v2)
    vetor1.append(v1)
    vetor2.append(v2)
    resultante.append(v)

print(f'O primeiro vetor é: {vetor1}')
print(f'O segundo vetor é: {vetor2}')
print(f'O vetor resultante é: {resultante}')
```

Observe que apenas um **for** é capaz de inserir os valores de cada um dos dois primeiros vetores e, também, do vetor resultante.

Answer (score 0):

Se o que eu entendi está correto, você quer receber os valores sem ter que utilizar uma estrutura de repetição, você pode utilizar o map + split e transformar em uma lista:

```
n = int(input('Digite valor para N: '))

# os números devem ser digitados com um espaço entre eles, exemplo:
# 1 2 3 4
vetor1 = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores do vetor 1 separados por espaço: ').split()))
vetor2 = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores do vetor 2 separados por espaço: ').split()))

resultante = [elemvetor1 * elemvetor2  for elemvetor1, elemvetor2 in zip(vetor1, vetor2)]

print(f'Resultado final: {" ".join(str(v) for v in resultante)}')
```

Entrada:

```
Digite valor para N: 5
Digite os valores do vetor 1 separados por espaço: 1 3 2 4 5
Digite os valores do vetor 2 separados por espaço: 6 8 9 7 6
```

Saída:

```
Resultado final: 6 24 18 28 30
```